# Image, Photo Quality in IOS

Tags: ios, image, swift

I was building small Image sharing app that just add text on the image and can save to the Album in IOS. as i implemented its just use screenshot of the screen and crop it and save to the gallery.and it reduced the quality. but when i search other apps in Appstore its not like  that. after editing and saving to the gallery still image is in super quality. example like instagram and other photo editing app.

i have searched everywhere in the stackoverflow and other websites im getting same screenshot concept.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size,true,2.0)
        self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.view.bounds,
           afterScreenUpdates: true)

        newImage =
        UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

How to make it with good quality?

Answer (score 0):

Using this line of code you are scaling the image up so you are losing quality.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size,true,2.0)
```

Try this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size,true,1.0)
```

This will make sure that the image is the same scale, meaning that it will not lose quality.